# application/soap+msbin1 in android

Tags: android, json, web-services, soap

I just need to send request to webservice via normal HTTP POST inorder to get response.I passed required parameter on body well.While i run it.,i got "Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/json' was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'." error.When i made research over this.,due to "Web Service required the request to have a specific Content-Type, namely "application/soap+msbin1".When i replaced expected content type.,i got Bad Request error.I donno how to recover from that.

My code:
...

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ResponseHandler <String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("My URL");
    postMethod.setHeader( "Content-Type", "text/json"); 
    postMethod.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache"); 



    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("userName", "My Username");
    json.put("password", "My Password");
    json.put("isPersistent",false);


    postMethod.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
    HttpResponse  response = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
```

...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to call WCF SOAP service. That service expects correct SOAP communication (= no JSON) and moreover it uses MS binary message encoding of SOAP messages (that is what content type describes) is not interoperable so I doubt you will be able to use it on Android device (unless you find implementation of that encoding for Java / Android).

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);    
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                             entity.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");                            entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
                             request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                             request.setEntity(entity); 

try{
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    response = httpClient.execute(request); 
}
```

Try using something like this. it worked for me.

Thanks.
N_JOY.